# Unexpected pandas.Series.replace() behavior

Tags: python, pandas

Given this -

`import pandas as pd`

`s = pd.Series(['', '1', '2', '', '4', '', '6'])`

Why does this -

`s.replace('', None).values`

Result in this -

`array(['', '1', '2', '2', '4', '4', '6'], dtype=object)`

When I would expect this -

`array([None, '1', '2', None, '4', None, '6'], dtype=object)`

Comment: Use `s.replace([''],[None]).values` for now which is same as what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of None is problematic there. If you pass None for an argument, it will use the default value for that ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html)):

> None
>
> The sole value of types.NoneType. None is frequently used to
> represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not
> passed to a function.

So `s.replace('', None)` is the same as `s.replace('')`. Apparently the default action when no value is passed is to forward fill the Series. Instead, you can use np.nan:

```
pd.Series(['', '1', '2', '', '4', '', '6']).replace('', np.nan)
Out: 
0    NaN
1      1
2      2
3    NaN
4      4
5    NaN
6      6
dtype: object
```

Or pass a dict:

```
s.replace({'': None})
Out: 
0    None
1       1
2       2
3    None
4       4
5    None
6       6
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is utterly utterly confusing (and dangerous) behavior. The library should have been written with a marker object for the default value e.g. replace(...,  value=MISSING_TOKEN, ), and allow a value of None.