# pandas replace NaN to None exhibits counterintuitive behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Given a series

```
s = pd.Series([1.1, 1.2, np.nan])
s
0    1.1
1    1.2
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

If the need arises to convert the NaNs to None (to, for example, work with parquets), then I would like to have

```
0     1.1
1     1.2
2    None
dtype: object
```

I would assume `Series.replace` would be the obvious way of doing this, but here's what the function returns:

```
s.replace(np.nan, None)

0    1.1
1    1.2
2    1.2
dtype: float64
```

The NaN was forward filled, instead of being replaced. Going through the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), I see that if the second argument is None, then the first argument should be a dictionary. Based on this, I would expect `replace` to either replace as intended, or throw an exception.

I believe the workaround here is

```
pd.Series([x if pd.notna(x) else None for x in s], dtype=object) 
0     1.1
1     1.2
2    None
dtype: object
```

Which is fine. But I would like to understand why this behaviour occurs, whether it is documented, or if it is just a bug and I have to dust off my git profile and log one on the issue tracker... any ideas?

Comment: `s.where(s.notnull(),None)` is another cleaner workaround I guess

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Thank you! Will file that away for future reference...

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Hmm, I don't believe so, this question is specifically with respect to the behaviour of replace. What do you think?

Comment: I believe this is in the docs: `The method to use when for replacement, when to_replace is a scalar, list or tuple and value is None`. when referring to method parameter, so when value is None the method used is pad (the default)

Comment: to me this looks like a bug, I would expect it to throw an exception or do nothing, forward filling is incorrect, I would file this as an issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: "The method to use when for replacement, when to_replace is a scalar, list or tuple and value is None." Can you specify in which part it says if second argument is None the first should be a dictionary?

Comment: @ayhan Sure, in the docs section under the `to_replace` argument, it says "Dicts can be used to specify different replacement values for different existing values. [...] To use a dict in this way the value parameter should be None."

Comment: @coldspeed Yes now I get it it is different. The worst part now is I am going through some of my own implementations just to check whether a bug has creeped in because of this. Thanks for the question! `s.replace(np.nan, None)` is in fact counterintuitive when it forward fills

Comment: this works `s.replace({np.nan:None})` but I'd expect the less verbose method to behave the same

Comment: That's the other way around though. If you pass a dict, then value should be None. That doesn't mean if the value is None `to_replace` should be a dict though?

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for weighing in, and for the suggested workaround-that is even cleaner! I guess I'll get to filing that bug soon...

Comment: @ayhan Now that you mention it...

Comment: Here's Nicki's [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663225/unexpected-pandas-series-replace-behavior#comment68557738_40663225). We might close that as a duplicate if you get an authoritative response to this one.

Comment: @ayhan Two years and still the same thing :D This is a dupe, so I will close it, but I think it is worth investigating...

Comment: @ayhan If you think it is better left open for a dev to write an answer, then feel free to reopen... I am fine with anything.

Comment: I believe it was not documented when I wrote that answer. I remember figuring it out by trial and error. Let's give this some time if anybody wants to investigate further.

Comment: See: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19998

Answer (score 7):

This behaviour is in the documentation of the `method` parameter:

```
method : {‘pad’, ‘ffill’, ‘bfill’, None}

The method to use when for replacement, when to_replace is a scalar, list or tuple and value is None.
```

So in your example `to_replace` is a *scalar*, and `value` is `None`. The method by default is `pad`, from the documentation of [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid
```

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the NaNs are forward filled, though?

Comment: Well that would suggest `s.replace(np.nan, None, method=None)` would work but it doesn't and borks

Comment: @coldspeed the method by default is pad

Comment: So, you're saying `s.replace(np.nan, None)` is treated to be `s.replace(np.nan, None, method='pad')` and hence forward filled? Hmm, that does make sense, but I don't know if it is the intended behaviour or the right behaviour to display in this case.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes, from the documentation that is what it seems.

Comment: It is possible this is by design, and that the only way to replace NaNs to None is using a dictionary as EdChum observed. I can accept this explanation, although I would like some closure from the devs. Will open an issue and see what they say. Thanks for shedding some light on this!

Comment: @EdChum Setting the second argument to `None` overwrites the method though.

Comment: To me this is unexpected, it's a special edge case which is not what I would expect given that if there was no match say `s.replace('foo',None)` then it would return the original series unchanged

Comment: @ayhan sorry I don't understand, you mean you expect this to work: `s.replace(np.nan, value=None, method=None)` or that passing `None` has unintended consequences?

Comment: @EdChum I believe `value=None` triggers `method='pad'` so `method=None` is ignored (based on the order of arguments). I agree it is unintuitive but I think it works as documented.

Comment: @ayhan ah OK, to me this is weird, it will probably not be changed given it's documented but it's unexpected to me, I wouldn't expect this behaviour, normally nothing happens or the exact matched value is replaced, I wouldn't use `replace` to `ffill` or `bfill` as a consequence